# Increase number of review audits when there are fewer posts to review

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, review-audits

Would it be worthwhile to make the number of review-audits you receive more elastic based on queue size: When there are less posts available for review, you get more review-audits. When there is a lot of actual posts available, you get less audits. This would seem to have the following benefits:

1. During high volumes, posts are reviewed quickly without losing too much time on review-audits.
2. During low volumes, users get to refine review skills and low quality reviewers are identified more effectively.

An example implementation of this could be:

- Review queue < 3 posts: Review-audit probability 25%
- Review queue < 200 posts: Review-audit probability 8%
- Review queue >= 200 posts: Review-audit probability 2%

I think it is currently a 5% probability regardless of queue size, but gets reduced temporarily if a user gets a lot of review-audits correct in a row. That should not conflict with this proposal at all.

Comment: Maybe always do a audit before saying "nothing is left in queue"