# Awful lot of audits?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

So, I'm noticing in the Late Answers and First Posts queues that maybe 25-35% of answers shown to me to review are audits. (5 out of the last 16 reviews in LA, 4 out of the last 13 in FP. All of them passed.) Is that a normal rate for someone with my rep and half-decent audit record?

I would give a more precise count, but it's pretty tedious to open all the links from my review history and manually count which were what, so I just used what was in my tab history.

Comment: Clarify much more...what you want to ask?

Comment: Wondering if that's really how many audits is normal or if something is weird. No idea how to make it clearer than that.

Comment: This is usual rate of audit...But as I am also seeing that more users are participating in it due to Winter Bash. So here are many users auditing who are inactive in audits from many days. Hope so that could a reason.

Comment: FWIW, I've been using up all my reviews every day since I hit 500, so that hasn't changed.

Comment: I'd say it's above the norm. Probably it's the devil's circle here: the more audits you fail, the more you get. The more audits you get, the more you failed (because a lot of audits are "broken by design").

Comment: @Р̀СТȢѸ́ФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ That's the craziest user name I've seen yet. You didn't want people to find you on SO?

Comment: @Okuma.Scott it's a continous test for SO layout formatting etc. as well.

Comment: I'd say it's normal because LA&FP are pretty empty queues, so you only get a low amount of reviews at a time. Every time you start a new review session, the probability of an audit also increases. I've noticed this when I started switching the filters in the Close Queue that I get more review audits.

Comment: @Р̀СТȢѸ́ФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ: is there really no better way to test this site, e.g. through dev.SO??

Comment: One important thing to note is that audits seem (anecdotally at any rate) to happen more often when a queue is low or empty. Both of those are perpetually empty

Comment: @Artjom, that's probably the cause. I have a script to pick up new queue entries more efficiently, so I'd guess it's starting a new session every time. I guess http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266372/4099598 got implemented after all?